# App Store Connect There is a new version of your paid application agreement, How to solve？

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to add an app to itunesconnect. There is a new protocol available, but I can't click to agree?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYRas.png)

[image]

Comment: make sure it's your apple account and you have admin role. is it ?

Comment: I found this account is not an administrator rights account, has been resolved, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure it's your apple account and you have admin role. Without admin role you can't do it. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll to the bottom of the agreement to enable the submit button.